# Charting a line graph enabling variable number of data series

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, charts

I have been trying to get the Silverlight charting toolkit to allow me to have a variable number of series based on the data. 
A single line graph is easy you have two data points in my case NumberOfDays is the X axis and CountOfItems is the value to be graphed. 
Now I want to be able to say

```
Product 1, Day 1, 10 items
Product 2, Day 1, 8 items.
Product 1, Day 2, 12 items
Product 2, Day 2, 20 items.
```

And so on with a nice graph having 2 lines (products 1 and 2).
The trick here is that I don't know how many products are going to be returned, it could be 2 or 10 and I just want to return any number of series out.

The 2 charting technologies we are trailing this with are the MS Silverlight toolkit and ComponentOne.

Answer (score 0):

With the MS Silverlight toolkit just make one series per product and put those series into the chart. The Chart takes a collection of series so you can have as many as you want.